# Can i store 2 * 12bit unsigned numbers in a file as 3 bytes in C++ using bit fields?

Tags: c++, file, compression, byte

I`m working on an LZW compression app in C++. Since there are no data types that can store 12 bit numbers for representing table elements up to 4095 I thought that I can store 2 of those nrs as 3 bytes in a file and then read them as a struct with 2 unsigned short members. Is there a way to do that or I should just use unsigned short? This is what I have tried but it stores 4 bytes as there are 2 unsigned short members.

```
#define BITS 12

struct LZWStruct {
    unsigned short code1 : BITS;
    unsigned short code2 : BITS;
};

int main() {
    LZWStruct test;
    test.code1 = 144;
    test.code2 = 233;

    FILE* f = fopen("binary.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&test, sizeof(test), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: instead of "is there a way?" better ask "how to do it?" and show what you tried so far. The answer to "is there a way?" is often just a "Yes" but thats not the answer you want to get

Comment: The details of bitfields is compiler specific, and (very likely) may not be portable, and there is no guarantee that the compiler will bit twiddle in the way you want (in those situations where you care about those details).  If you do the masking and shifting yourself, you can guarantee the layout.  Although you may still have endian concerns to worry about, too.

Comment: There is no guarantee on how the bit fields are laid out in your struct. So your struct could still be bigger than 4 bytes. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/oT7a4d9G9) example shows, that clang, msvc and gcc all use 6 bytes for a struct with your specifications.

Comment: 3 * 12 bits is 36 bits. 4 * 8 bits is 32 bits. Won't fit, no matter what language. | Or is the question title out of sync with the actual question? SInce that seems to talk only about storing two such numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title and question body are two different questions with different answers.

*No*, you absolutely cannot store 3 * 12-bit unsigned numbers (36 bits) in four bytes (32 bits).

Yes, you can store two 12-bit numbers (24 bits) in three bytes (24 bits).

The bit fields in C++, inherited from C, that you are trying to use do not guarantee exactly how the bits are packed in the structure, so you cannot know which three bytes in the structure have your data. You should simply use the shift and or operators to put them in an integer. Then you will know exactly which three bytes to write to the file.

Then to be portable, in particular not dependent on the endianess of the machine, you should write bytes from the integer also using the shift operator. If you write using a pointer to the integer, it won't be portable.

In your example, you could have tried `fwrite(&test, 3, 1, f)`, and it might work,  *if* the compiler put the codes in the low bits of `test`, *and if* your machine is little-endian. Otherwise, no.

So to do it reliably:

Put in an integer:

```
unsigned short code1;
unsigned short code2;
uint32_t test = (code1 & 0x3ff) | ((uint32_t)(code2 & 0x3ff) << 12);
```

Write to a file:

```
putc(test, f);
putc(test >> 8, f);
putc(test >> 16, f);
```

You can skip the intermediate step if you like:

```
putc(code1, f);
putc(((code1 >> 8) & 0xf) | (code2 << 4), f);
putc(code2 >> 4, f);
```

(In the above I am assuring that I only store the low 12 bits of each code with the `&` operators, in case the bits above the low 12 are not zero. If you know for certain that the code values are less than 4096, then you can remove the `&` operations above.)

Comment: Yea this is what I wanted, thanks, but how can I do the reverse operation (reading those bytes and assign them to 2 unsigned short variables) ?

Comment: I will leave that as an exercise for the reader. If you understand how this works and the `<<`, `>>`, `|`, and '&' operations, it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), multiple adjacent bit fields are usually packed together. The special unnamed bit field of size zero can be forced to break up padding. It specifies that the next bit field begins at the beginning of its allocation unit. Use sizeof to verify the size of your structure.

The exact packing, however, may depend on platform and compiler. This may be less a problem if the data are later loaded by the same program, or some closely related, but may be an issue for some generic format.